# Form validation Issue

Tags: jquery, validation, label, watermark

I am using jQuery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for form validation. The problem I am facing is when I have inline labels..

For Example:

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" value="Enter your ....">
```

This is the sample case where validation is failing because the 'value' is set for input field. Is there any workaround? How do I ignore default/label values?

Comment: validation fails because the plugin considers "Enter your..." as input which infact is just a label for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make/add a method for that..

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exception", function(value, element) { 
  return this.optional(element) || value == "Enter your ...."; 
}, "message if bad");
```

then use `exception : true`...

more on [addMethod()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod)